# AWS Certificate Manager "In use" status "No"

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl

I was **imported** SSL certificate using AWS Certificate manager and it will display **In Use** status as **No** and my Subdomain didn't work with `https`.

Below image displayed the status as I described. What was the reason for that?

[image]

Edit: I used Amazon EC2 with ubuntu box.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The AWS Certificate Manager provides SSL certificates for use in a limted set of AWS services:

From [What Is AWS Certificate Manager](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-overview.html)?

> You cannot install an ACM Certificate directly on your website or
> application. You must install your certificate by using one of the
> services integrated with ACM. For more information about these
> services, see Services Integrated with AWS Certificate Manager.

These integrated services are:

- Elastic Load Balancing
- Amazon CloudFront
- AWS Elastic Beanstalk
- Amazon API Gateway

It appears you have not configured your ACM SSL to be used in one of these services.

A common misconception is that you can use ACM SSL in any HTTP server on an instance - you cannot. You need to use an ELB infront of any webserver in order to properly configure HTTPS.

Comment: That mean we need to create load balancers in EC2 ?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use ACM for the website.  I have some non-customer loads where I have only one instance behind an ELB just to enable SSL using ACM.

Comment: Above answer was helpful, when you change all references of ACM, the old expired certificate will automatically turns in to "In use? "-> No and newly created certificate with "in use?"-> Yes.

A Good idea if you don't know at how many places it's configured, refere above services(and more if you know), and check for old and new certificate "In Use" status and look until old certificate gets to No status.

Answer (score 10):

You need to go to CloudFront and modify your distribution to point to the new ACM Certificate that you just got. CloudFront will then pick up the new cert and deploy it to your distribution for you. ACM will then mark the certificate as "in use". As long as it's then "in-use", ACM will renew it for you and continue to update CloudFront.

Comment: yeah, it's useful for me. thank you.